# Logic to Calculate current Download speed

Tags: python, download-speed

I have been trying to calculate the current download speed as the file is being downloaded (not average) using Python's requests module. Searched on google  , but could not find a definite solution . What is the logic to calculate the download speed? Should I keep track of how many bytes have been downloaded per sec ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: There isn’t an ‘instantaneous’ download speed, so you will have to average over a smaller period like a second, or a fraction of a second and then multiply that number to express it in e.g. bytes/second. Please edit a minimal complete verifiable example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve based on your current code into the question, and explain what it doesn’t do that you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu OS, then you can simply install speedtest-cli to check your internet speed. Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install speedtest-cli
```

Then just type speedtest-cli in terminal

Comment: The OP wants to know the speed of the current download, not that of their internet connection.